# Was Po's evil side indicative of his true feelings?

Tags: magic, kung-fu-panda

In Kung Fu Panda: Legends of Awesomeness, Season 1 Episode 10, we see that Po is split into two parts - his good part and his bad part. We see that the bad Po develops friendship with Crocodiles, insults his own master and single-handily defeats the Furious Five.

My question is, does that means that some part of Po always wanted to develop friendship with the Crocodiles and insult his own master, something which is never shown in any of the other episodes of the entire series. Was it just suppressing his desire to befriend crocodiles and insult his irritating master all this time?

Comment: I'll just leave [this](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EvilTwin) and [this](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LiteralSplitPersonality) right here.

Comment: The question asks about specifics about Po, but then says it's about other movies' concepts. Not sure which one it is.

Comment: I've focused the question on Kung Fu Panda, revert the edit if you disagree with the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea of being split into two can be broken down into different concepts

**Good vs Evil**

example: Good Ash vs Bad Ash in [*Army of Darkness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Army_of_Darkness).

Here, we have our character who is generally seen as inherently "good". The clone/twin is inherently evil. The evil character is often a "mirror" or complete opposite of the original hero.

**Trait/Quality Splits**

example: Xander Harris in *Buffy: The Vampire Slayer* episode "[The Replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Replacement)."

Here, we have our character whose personality traits or qualities are pulled into separate beings. Instead of a character sometimes being confident or sometimes timid, Being A will always be confident while Being B will always be timid.

While these may seem awfully similar, there is a major difference: with trait/quality splits, the separate beings are just distilled traits and qualities. A character who is inherently good usually does not have a fully evil side, so their twin would not be evil.

**So Where does that leave Po?**

Po was split into two by [The Mystical Mirror of Yin and Yang](https://kungfupanda.fandom.com/wiki/Mystical_Mirror_of_Yin_and_Yang), which is described as

> a mirror that possesses magical properties to separate its viewer into two beings — one representing the viewer's good nature, and the other their evil nature.

So, here we have the Good vs Evil split. [Bad Po](https://kungfupanda.fandom.com/wiki/Bad_Po_%28character%29) is the exact opposite of Good Po and is described as

> As the physical manifestation of Po's evil nature, Bad Po was purely evil in all intentions. As described by Shifu, Bad Po possessed all the qualities and traits of regular Po's Dragon Warrior side (often used when he fights) — of such include aggression, indignation and impatience.

So, without the Good vs Evil split, Po never would have done any of those things. Nor would he have ever really even thought about them.